# Can my coffee maker brew stronger coffee?

Tags: consumer-products

The product description for the [Hamilton Beach Coffee maker](https://www.hamiltonbeach.com/flexbrew-2-way-coffee-maker-49976) notes that I can:

> **Choose Your Brew Strength**
>     Get your preferred brew flavor with two
>   brewing strengths – choose from bold or regular.

If the same volume of water and ground coffee is used, how is it possible to affect the strength of the coffee?  On the machine itself is just a button that toggles between "Regular" and "Bold", and I am unable to detect a difference between the two modes.

Comment: Not a question for this site, but what it basically does is restrict flow _out_ of the same volume of water while it is with the grounds so it steeps in the coffee longer to make it more bold.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Where should I go instead to address claims made by consumer products?  I has assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that this is what the 'consumer-products' tag was for.

Comment: The [Coffee StackExchange](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/) site might help you get a good answer. Skeptics usually focuses more on pseudo-scientific/outlandish/fringe claims than what you would find in a normal product's manual. If the claim was more along the lines of "this coffee maker only needs half the coffee beans as other machines" then it would probably fit here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the mechanics of coffee makers.

Comment: Obviously, there will be differences in interpretation, but from what I read in the help center an meta site, this is on topic.  A manufacturer has made a claim about its product that, in order to be true, must be based on some sound engineering principles. JasonR above noted one way that this can be achieved which this particular product does not do.  I understand that this question is not glamorous or controversial, but this would seem to be the case for every question posted under the consumer-products tag.  If you'd rather not address questions like this, I recommend removing the tag.